# how to hide dynamically an div container in AMP Page

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Are there some solution as how to hide an div container dynamically?

this is my current implementation:

```
<button class="button" on="tap:player.hide">hide me</button>
<button class=button" on="tap:player.show">show me</button>    
<div id="player" class="show" [class]="show||hide">some content</div>

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

which works as long the div class has the value 'show' in initial call. 
But what i want is to disable the container-view as long the buttons hasn't been clicked...

Comment: Remove the bind expression `[class]="show||hide"`. Also do you need it to be visible at start or not visible at start?

Comment: as long the div is set to visbile it works as expected, only when its view is disabled at start, then no content will appear after the show button gets clicked...i got an message within my developer tool which indicated to disable the div dynamically in order to works.....the question how to do it?

Comment: Did you try deleting `class="show" [class]="show||hide"` this part? It is not really needed if you are using `player.hide` and `player.show` functions.

Comment: @ChristianFelix https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242350/5635098 hope this help you.

Comment: @bachcha-singh, thank you, it works!

Comment: @ChristianFelix you can achieve your goal without using amp-bind also, check my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answered by Sebastian Benz with amp-bind : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239075/amp-easy-way-to-toggle-a-css-class/45242350#45242350)

You can achieve your goal without amp-bind also

[Here is working url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGwExe)

Code

```
<button id="playerbutton1" class="button" hidden on="tap:player.hide,playerbutton1.hide,playerbutton2.show">hide me</button>
<button id="playerbutton2" class="button" on="tap:player.show,playerbutton2.hide,playerbutton1.show">show me</button>    
<div id="player" hidden>some content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with Actions and Events: [link](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/)

```
<button on="tap:player.toggleVisibility">Toggle</button>

<div id="player" hidden>some content</div>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/felipelima/7h0tp6q5)

AMP hint: CSS hide/show and visibility do not work with tap event

Answer (score 1):

This looks the cleanest for me.

```html
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({openMenu: !openMenu})">Toggle</button>

<div [hidden]="openMenu">some content</div>
```